# Sitecore Analytics

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-dms

I am on 7.2 version and found that Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive is false and Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Visitor.VisitorClassification is 0

Imp point to note here is that my Analytics is working for all admin pages but not for custom pages of my site

Can some one please provide some suggestions

Cheers 
LA

Comment: Is Is you page session-enabled? Is `Analytics.Enabled` set to `true` in the `Sitecore.Analytics.config`? Are your logs clear of errors related to `startTrackingPipeline`? If you answer "no" to any of these, `Tracker.IsActive` will be set to false.

Answer (score 2):

Your pages should have a **VisitorIdentification** tag, so that Sitecore will be able to collect tracking information. Please make sure you have got a correct tracking tag being set up on your custom page layouts.Below are examples for WebForms and MVC versions of Sitecore(correspondingly).

WebForms:

```
<sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" />
```

MVC:

```
@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
```

More information (links):

http://www.letsdositecore.com/scvisitoridentification/
https://learningwiththecurve.wordpress.com/tag/analytics/

Hope that helps!

**Update:** Please also read a note (How to ensure that your analytic are turned on Sitecore) by this link https://goo.gl/n53XsO to see how it works

Comment: Thanks Martin i am already doing this but can't see any results what i did not got here is 'correct tracking tag' . How do you set the Tracking tag

Comment: Depending on type of your project, wether it is WebForms or MVC, place appropriate tracking tag i quoted above onto your layout / rendering / sublayout - and this will work!  I have updated my original answer (at the bottom) with the link on how to ensure Analytics is enbabled.

Comment: i have put in <sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" /> but still no data am i missing some settings do i need to VisitorClassification as my VisitorClassificationId is 0