# Sitecore 7.2 engagement analytics not recording data

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-dms, personalization

I'm using Sitecore 7.2 DMS (Digital Marketing System) to personalize content based on pattern cards. The problem I'm having is that the engagement analytics tool is not recording any data.

I already troubleshooted the problem based on this [post](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/08/Troubleshooting-Analytics-is-Disabled-with-the-Sitecore-Customer-Engagement-Platform.aspx) but I haven't had any luck. Summarizing I checked:

- Sitecore.Analytics.config is in the Include folder
- The Analytics DB connection string is correct
- Analytics.DisableDatabase is false

  I even add the enableAnalytics in the web.config (true by default)

  ```
     <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableAnalytics="true" />
  ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just for clarity, is this set also: <setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="true" />

Comment: Is your Sitecore license enabled for Sitecore Analytics?`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from configuration, your pages should have a VisitorIdentification tag, so that Sitecore will be able to collect tracking information. Please make sure you have got a correct tracking tag being set up on your custom page layouts.Below are examples for WebForms and MVC versions of Sitecore(correspondingly).

WebForms:

```
<sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" />
```

MVC:

```
@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
```

See previous SO question on that:
[Sitecore Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854678/sitecore-analytics/31854962)

Answer (score -1):

Disable Bots detection in the Sitecore Analytics config file. by default its true. Make it to false.

Comment: Don't disable bots.  The visitor identification tag mentioned by Martin ensures your site traffic isn't categorized as a bot.